# What is the version of High Efficiency AAC on Android?

Tags: android, format, voice

For HE_AAC, there exist two version including version 1 and 2. In android document, it doesn't mention the version of HE_AAC.

Anyone know about it??

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core), Android supports both HE-AACv1 (AAC+) and HE-AACv2 (enhanced AAC+).

Comment: But, In this page (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html), it does not mention the verison of HE-ACC.